# Need tutorial for custom DialogPropertyValueEditor workflow foundation 4.0

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I have a custom activity which has inargument<MyClass>.
MyClass has several properties.

I want to provide a popup dialog editor for this inargument which will present a form, to input the values of all properties.

Is there any good example, tutorial showing all the steps to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wfprerelease/thread/c690a652-4497-4c2b-895f-e0c8be4656f1